# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in view blade

Tags: php, laravel, controller, sql-update, sql-insert

this is my code what should I do ? is not read in my project what's wrong with this code? am I wrong to write this code?
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\rezkastore\resources\views\pages\daftar_supplier.blade.php)

```
@foreach($daftar_supplier as $daftar_supplier)
    <div class="modal fade" id="editModal-{{ $daftar_supplier->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title mb-0" id="addModalLabel">Tambah Data Pelanggan</h5>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                 <!-- Card body -->
                <form role="form" action="{{ route('daftar_supplier.update', $daftar_supplier->id) }}" method="POST">
                  @csrf
                  @method('POST')
                    <!-- Input groups with icon -->
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="addNamaSupplier" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Nama</label>
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="nama" value="{{ $daftar_supplier->nama_supplier }}" id="updateNamaSupplier" name="updateNamaSupplier" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="updateAlamat" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Alamat</label>
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="alamat" value="{{ $daftar_supplier->alamat }}" id="updateAlamat" name="updateAlamat" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="updateNoTelp" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">No.Telp</label>
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="notelp" value="{{ $daftar_supplier->no_telp }}" id="updateNoTelp" name="updateNoTelp" required>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="updateEmail" class="col-md-2 col-form-label form-control-label">Email</label>
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" value="{{ $daftar_supplier->email }}" id="updateEmail" name="updateEmail" required>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah Data</button>
            </div>
            </form>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

this is the controller of view

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
            $update_supplier = DaftarSupplier::findOrFail($id);
            $update_supplier->nama_supplier = $request->updateNamaSupplier;
            $update_supplier->alamat = $request->updateAlamat;
            $update_supplier->no_telp = $request->updateNoTelp;
            $update_supplier->email = $request->updateEmail;
            $update_supplier->save();

            if($update_supplier){
                Alert::success(' Berhasil Update Data ', ' Silahkan dicek kembali');
            }elseif(!$update_supplier){
                Alert::error('data gagal disimpan ', ' Silahkan coba lagi');
            }
            return redirect()->back();
    }
```

this is the route

```
//Daftar Supplier
     Route::get('daftar_supplier','\App\Http\Controllers\DaftarSupplierController@index')->name('daftar_supplier');
     Route::post('daftar_supplier/create','\App\Http\Controllers\DaftarSupplierController@create')->name('daftar_supplier.create');
     Route::delete('daftar_supplier/delete/{id}','\App\Http\Controllers\DaftarSupplierController@delete')->name('daftar_supplier.delete');
     Route::put('daftar_supplier/update/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\DaftarSupplierController@update')->name('daftar_supplier.update');
```

please help

Comment: add ```dd($pelanggan)``` inside your ```foreach``` loop to see what is inside

Comment: into the contoller or view blade?
how to write it?

Comment: after ```foreach``` loop just put this code ```{{ dd($pelanggan) }}```

Comment: One problem which is very evident from the first line in blade view is `@foreach($daftar_supplier as $daftar_supplier)` Pls make it a point to have differentiation in name between variable name for collection and a single record. `@foreach($daftar_suppliers as $daftar_supplier)` sounds very logical and also gives an idea that we are iterating over a collection of daftar_suppliers

Comment: `id="editModal-{{ $daftar_supplier->id }}"` could throw an error because it may also mean that you are trying to access id property on a collection instead of an object. Change to `@foreach($daftar_suppliers as $daftar_supplier)` and check again if the error still persists

Comment: If you still get the same error after the rectification suggest in above comment and with detailed explanation in my answer below, pls post the code for controller action/method which renders the edit view - blade form included in your question

Comment: thank youu @Donkarnash it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely not passing `$daftar_supplier` to the view in your controller. It should be at the end of `DaftarSupplierController@index` which you haven't shared. In general, you should pass an array of data to the view according to https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views

Also, it's best practice to use a different variable name for the array and value in your `@foreach` loop, for example:

```
@foreach($daftar_suppliers as $daftar_supplier)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make it a point to follow a simple convention for naming variables.

***Singular for a single Object or Record*** - $daftar_supplier for a single record/object

***Plural for collection of records*** - $daftar_suppliers for collection of daftar_supplier records

This not only makes it easy to read and understand the code - it also avoids ambiguity during runtime.

In the snippet from blade view in the question `@foreach($daftar_supplier as $daftar_supplier)` uses exactly same variable name for collection as well as individual single records when looping over the collection.

Such naming conventions not only make the code hard to read and understand it also creates ambiguity during runtime.

So `id="editModal-{{ $daftar_supplier->id }}"` could be evaluated at runtime as if you are trying to access `id` property on a collection rather than a single object.

And naturally the `id` is a property on individual record within the collection, while collection itself does not have an `id` property so an error may be thrown during runtime.

Comment: thank you for your explanation and knowledge